# Erro Requisição AJAX - success não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, webforms

Boa tarde galera,

Tenho a seguinte requisição AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
           url: "/membros.aspx/populaGridMembros",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (result) {
             populaTabela(result);
           },
           error: function() {
             alert("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os dados.");
           }
        });
    });
```

O método populaTabela, pega o resultado da função populaGridMembros e inseri em uma table na página.

O problema é que quando executo este código na página, não ocorre um erro na requisição AJAX, mas não entra no parâmetro success. Na depuração do firefox descobri que após ele executar todo esse código javascript, ou seja, durante o debug passo por todos os parâmetros da função $.ajax(url, type, dataType, contentType, success e error a função $.ajax retorna os valores retornados pela função populaGridMembros da url e exibi uma janela com a seguinte informação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço!!!

Segue o código da função populaTabela:

```
function populaTabela(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var j in data) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + data[j].NOME + "</td><td>" +
                "</td><td>" + data[j].SOBRENOME + "</td><td>" +
                "</td><td>" + data[j].RG + "</td><td>" +
                "</td><td>" + data[j].CPF + "</td><td></tr>";
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código da função `populaTabela()`?

Comment: Boa tarde Sergio, obrigado por avaliar minha pergunta. Adicionei o código da função na pergunta.

Comment: Qual o código HTTP que `/membros.aspx/populaGridMembros` está retornando?

Comment: O que `repsonse` contém? Utilize `console.log` ou inspecione a resposta diretamente no navegador.

Comment: @AlexandreNascimento uma vez que estás a usar `dataType: "json",` parece-me que esta linha é redundante: `var data = JSON.parse(response);` podes fazer `console.log(response);` no inicio dessa função? o que dá na consola?

Comment: Não apenas redundante como disse o @Sergio, mas talvez a causa do problema.

Comment: Também pensei e retirei essa linha de código, o problema é que nem entra rotina do success. Quando chega no success o valor que a função /membros.aspx/populaGridMembros deveria retornar ainda não está retornado, é como se o response ainda não estivesse ocorrido, então quando chega no success o parâmetro result da function está com valor undefined, só depois que ele passa pelo error e termina todos os parâmetros é que a função $.ajax retorna o valores no responseText.